# Amazon Product advertisement API invalid xml response in php

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing web application using codeigniter. last 7 months ago i used this code and getting Product from amazon but last one month i dont get any product using this code. I also contact with script author he did not any response yet. any one can tell me where is the problem. Does anyone have a such as code that is using Amazon Product advertisement API.

aws_signed_request.php

```
function  aws_signed_request($region,$params,$public_key,$private_key,$associate_tag)
{

    $method = "GET";
    $host = "ecs.amazonaws.".$region; // must be in small case
    $uri = "/onca/xml";


    $params["Service"]          = "AWSECommerceService";
    $params["AWSAccessKeyId"]   = $public_key;
    $params["AssociateTag"]     = $associate_tag;
    $params["Timestamp"]        = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
    $params["Version"]          = "2009-03-31";

    /* The params need to be sorted by the key, as Amazon does this at
      their end and then generates the hash of the same. If the params
      are not in order then the generated hash will be different thus
      failing the authetication process.
    */
    ksort($params);

    $canonicalized_query = array();

    foreach ($params as $param=>$value)
    {
        $param = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($param));
        $value = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($value));
        $canonicalized_query[] = $param."=".$value;
    }

    $canonicalized_query = implode("&", $canonicalized_query);

    $string_to_sign = $method."\n".$host."\n".$uri."\n".$canonicalized_query;

    /* calculate the signature using HMAC with SHA256 and base64-encoding.
       The 'hash_hmac' function is only available from PHP 5 >= 5.1.2.
    */
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, $private_key, True));

    /* encode the signature for the request */
    $signature = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($signature));

    /* create request */
    $request = "http://".$host.$uri."?".$canonicalized_query."&Signature=".$signature;

    /* I prefer using CURL */
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    $xml_response = curl_exec($ch);

    /* If cURL doesn't work for you, then use the 'file_get_contents'
       function as given below.
    */

    if ($xml_response === False)
    {
        return False;
    }
    else
    {
        /* parse XML */
        $parsed_xml = @simplexml_load_string($xml_response);
        return ($parsed_xml === False) ? False : $parsed_xml;
    }
}
```

amazon_api_class.php

```
require_once 'aws_signed_request.php';

    class AmazonProductAPI
    {
        /**
         * Your Amazon Access Key Id
         * @access private
         * @var string
         */
        private $public_key     = "AKIAJF7UYAI77UYKXXXX";

        /**
         * Your Amazon Secret Access Key
         * @access private
         * @var string
         */
        private $private_key    = "ISEZ/SgZ9MV7OzTo5KRnkdhjotvp5tPCWnYLXXXX";

        /**
         * Your Amazon Associate Tag
         * Now required, effective from 25th Oct. 2011
         * @access private
         * @var string
         */
        private $associate_tag  = "uytuyerxpo1-20";

        /**
         * Constants for product types
         * @access public
         * @var string
         */

        /*
            Only three categories are listed here. 
            More categories can be found here:
            http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/APPNDX_SearchIndexValues.html
        */
        const MUSIC = "Music";
        const DVD   = "DVD";
        const GAMES = "VideoGames";


        /**
         * Check if the xml received from Amazon is valid
         * 
         * @param mixed $response xml response to check
         * @return bool false if the xml is invalid
         * @return mixed the xml response if it is valid
         * @return exception if we could not connect to Amazon
         */
        private function verifyXmlResponse($response)
        {
            if ($response === False)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not connect to Amazon");
            }
            else
            {
                if (isset($response->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Title))
                {
                    return ($response);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid xml response.");
                }
            }
        }


        /**
         * Query Amazon with the issued parameters
         * 
         * @param array $parameters parameters to query around
         * @return simpleXmlObject xml query response
         */
        private function queryAmazon($parameters)
        {
            return aws_signed_request("com", $parameters, $this->public_key, $this->private_key, $this->associate_tag);
        }


        /**
         * Return details of products searched by various types
         * 
         * @param string $search search term
         * @param string $category search category         
         * @param string $searchType type of search
         * @return mixed simpleXML object
         */
        public function searchProducts($search, $category, $searchType = "UPC")
        {
            $allowedTypes = array("UPC", "TITLE", "ARTIST", "KEYWORD");
            $allowedCategories = array("Music", "DVD", "VideoGames");

            switch($searchType) 
            {
                case "UPC" :    $parameters = array("Operation"     => "ItemLookup",
                                                    "ItemId"        => $search,
                                                    "SearchIndex"   => $category,
                                                    "IdType"        => "UPC",
                                                    "ResponseGroup" => "Medium");
                                break;

                case "TITLE" :  $parameters = array("Operation"     => "ItemSearch",
                                                    "Title"         => $search,
                                                    "SearchIndex"   => $category,
                                                    "ResponseGroup" => "Medium");
                                break;

            }

            $xml_response = $this->queryAmazon($parameters);

            return $this->verifyXmlResponse($xml_response);

        }


        /**
         * Return details of a product searched by UPC
         * 
         * @param int $upc_code UPC code of the product to search
         * @param string $product_type type of the product
         * @return mixed simpleXML object
         */
        public function getItemByUpc($upc_code, $product_type)
        {
            $parameters = array("Operation"     => "ItemLookup",
                                "ItemId"        => $upc_code,
                                "SearchIndex"   => $product_type,
                                "IdType"        => "UPC",
                                "ResponseGroup" => "Medium");

            $xml_response = $this->queryAmazon($parameters);

            return $this->verifyXmlResponse($xml_response);

        }


        /**
         * Return details of a product searched by ASIN
         * 
         * @param int $asin_code ASIN code of the product to search
         * @return mixed simpleXML object
         */
        public function getItemByAsin($asin_code)
        {
            $parameters = array("Operation"     => "ItemLookup",
                                "ItemId"        => $asin_code,
                                "ResponseGroup" => "Medium");

            $xml_response = $this->queryAmazon($parameters);

            return $this->verifyXmlResponse($xml_response);
        }


        /**
         * Return details of a product searched by keyword
         * 
         * @param string $keyword keyword to search
         * @param string $product_type type of the product
         * @return mixed simpleXML object
         */
        public function getItemByKeyword($keyword, $product_type)
        {
            $parameters = array("Operation"   => "ItemSearch",
                                "Keywords"    => $keyword,
                                "SearchIndex" => $product_type);

            $xml_response = $this->queryAmazon($parameters);

            return $this->verifyXmlResponse($xml_response);
        }

    }

?>
```

index.php

```
 include("amazon_api_class.php");

    $obj = new AmazonProductAPI();

    try
    {
        $result = $obj->getItemByAsin("B018L25LPC");
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Using proper functions like `http_build_query` to create your query string would be a good first step. Creating a [mcve] would be a good second step.

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0` seriously?